# Display bool in inspector from Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that contains 2 boolean variables. I am displaying the first one. Now I want to display the second boolean variable only and only if the first boolean variable is false. I am using custom inspector, how do I do this?

```
public bool myFirstBool = true;

[HideInInspector]
public bool mySecondBool = false;
```

My Editor Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor (typeof (ScriptMain))]

public class ScriptMainEditor : Editor {

    ScriptMain actualTarget;

    private void OnEnable () {

        actualTarget = (ScriptMain) target;

    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI () {
        DrawDefaultInspector (); // for other non-HideInInspector fields

        if (actualTarget.myFirstBool == true)
        {
          //Show mySecondBool in Inspector
        } else {
          //Hide mySecondBool in Inspector
        }
        base.OnInspectorGUI ();
    }

}
```

Comment: on your show code: actualTarget.mySecondBool = EditorGUILayout.Toogle("My second bool:", actualTarget.mySecondBool);

Comment: Thank you. This actually comes to the top of script. Can I display it under my myFirstBool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a proper editor script you don't go through the `target` at all except you know exactly what you are doing!

This

- doesn't mark changed fields and objects **dirty**
- thus doesn't save those values
- doesn't handle undo/redo
- doesn't handle prefab overwrites

Rather go through the [`SeriaizedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) and [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)s like

```
[CustomEditor (typeof (ScriptMain))]
public class ScriptMainEditor : Editor 
{
    SerializedProperty myFirstBool;
    SerializedProperty mySecondBool;

    private void OnEnable () 
    {
        // hook up the serialized properties
        myFirstBool = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ScriptMain.myFirstBool));
        mySecondBool = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ScriptMain.mySecondBool));
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI () 
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector (); // for other non-HideInInspector fields

        // update the current values into the serialized object and propreties
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if the first bool is true
        if (myFirstBool.boolValue)
        {
            // draw the second bool field
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(mySecondBool);
        }

        // Write back changed values
        // This also handles all marking dirty, saving, undo/redo etc
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You have created serializedProperty but no serializedObject. I am getting an error there.

Comment: @Vika [`serializedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-serializedObject.html) is a property of `Editor` which your editor inherits from ;)

Comment: @Vika that was a ypo I think I fixed already ;) it is `serializedObject`

Comment: Thank you yes. Such a long word and I missed an i :P But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@derHugo

> In a proper editor script you don't go through the target at all
> except you know exactly what you are doing!

If you dig into Editor class in unity you've got this [note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0w4c.png).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).